# How to solve IllegalStateException while loading the restful webapp in glassfish?

Tags: java, rest, jersey, glassfish-4

I am trying to create a basic Hello world app using [this link](https://www.mkyong.com/webservices/jax-rs/jersey-hello-world-example/).

I have created everything as asked but I am getting below error:

> Exception while loading the app : java.lang.IllegalStateException: ContainerBase.addChild: start: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: com.sun.research.ws.wadl.Response.getRepresentationOrFault()Ljava/util/Lis

My `web.xml`

```
<web-app id="WebApp_ID" version="2.4"
         xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee
        http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee/web-app_2_4.xsd">
    <display-name>Restful Web Application</display-name>

    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>jersey-serlvet</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>
            com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer
        </servlet-class>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>com.sun.jersey.config.property.packages</param-name>
            <param-value>com</param-value>
        </init-param>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>

    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>jersey-serlvet</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/rest/*</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>

</web-app>
```

[image: my dir structure]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**[`java.lang.NoSuchMethodError`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/NoSuchMethodError.html)** *an error can only occur at run time, if the definition of a class has incompatibly changed.*

I can see, you have compiled your code with `Jersey 1.8` and deployed your webapp on `Glassfish 4.1.1`.

And, as per one of the oracle **[official blog](https://blogs.oracle.com/theaquarium/glassfish-411-is-now-available)**, `Glassfish 4.1.1` has `Jersey 2.2`.

So, that conclude mismatch of jersey version (compiled with `Jersey 1.8`, but Glassfish is using `Jersey 2.2`). So, you are getting this exception at runtime.

The possible solution is to change your code to support `jersey 2.2` (of course replace libraries as well)